# "It will be the first time he has met her" - is it correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> They haven't met before and they are going to meet next week.

So is it right to say "It will be the first time he has met her."? I read it in a Economist article. So I was wondering how is this correct or why is this correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example sentence

> It will be the first time he has met her

is perfectly good and would be understood to mean they have not met before so this will be the first time.

You could also say

> Tomorrow will be the first time they *(have)* met.
>   They have not met each other yet, but after tomorrow they **will have met**.
>   After you pass the exam, you *(will)* **have met** all the requirements to graduate.